# Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager : BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

**Please note** I already tried the previous posts, but their not working for me.

I am having a problem with my Spring and Hibernate Configuration.

I think the reason is because it could not connect to my database, but I have the credentials in my properties file are all correct.
MySQL version is 5.5.44, Spring version is 4.0.2 and Hibernate version is 4.2.7.Final

This is the error of my tomcat.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mySessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.<init>(IZLjava/util/Timer;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
15-Oct-2015 13:22:45.620 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
15-Oct-2015 13:22:45.625 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/service] startup failed due to previous errors
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1648) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.7.0_80]
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.7.0_80]
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.7.0_80]
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.7.0_80]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487) [na:1.7.0_80]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97) [na:1.7.0_80]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328) [na:1.7.0_80]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420) [na:1.7.0_80]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848) [na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) [na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202) [na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199) [na:1.7.0_80]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198) [na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567) [na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828) [na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619) [na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684) [na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681) [na:1.7.0_80]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681) [na:1.7.0_80]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.<init>(IZLjava/util/Timer;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.<init>(IZLjava/util/Timer;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.createTaskRunner(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:145) ~[c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar:na]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.poolsInit(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:174) ~[c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar:na]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.<init>(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:295) ~[c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar:na]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getPoolManager(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:520) ~[c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar:na]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140) ~[c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1822) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1780) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1865) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431) ~[spring-orm-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416) ~[spring-orm-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 69 common frames omitted
```

This is my root context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:props.properties"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${locationdb.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
                org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.mypackage</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Location DB Datasource -->
<!-- When changing between database types, take note:
      * Change the driverClass and driverClassName below.
      * Update props.properties as needed (see: endpoint and Hibernate dialect)
-->

<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${locationdb.endpoint}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${locationdb.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${locationdb.password}"/>

    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${locationdb.c3p0.acquireIncrement}"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${locationdb.c3p0.minPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${locationdb.c3p0.maxPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${locationdb.c3p0.maxIdleTime}"/>
</bean>


<!-- Location DB MySQL Datasource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="${locationdb.endpoint}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${locationdb.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${locationdb.password}"/>
</bean>


<bean id="jedisConnFactory"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
      p:hostName="${jedis_endpoint}"
      p:port="${jedis_endpoint_port}"
      p:timeout="${jedis_timeout}"
      p:usePool="true"
      p:poolConfig-ref="jedisPoolConfig"/>

<bean id="serializer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>

<bean id="redisTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
      p:connectionFactory-ref="jedisConnFactory"
      p:defaultSerializer-ref="serializer"/>

<bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig"
      p:maxTotal="150"
      p:minIdle="5"
      p:maxIdle="15"/>

<!-- Job Manager -->
<bean id="jobManager" class="com.mypackage.restws.controllers.jobs.JobManager"/>


<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate"/>
```

and this is my props.properties

```
locationdb.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

locationdb.endpoint=jdbc:mysql://localhost/locationdb
locationdb.username=root
locationdb.password=root

locationdb.c3p0.acquireIncrement=1
locationdb.c3p0.minPoolSize=1
locationdb.c3p0.maxPoolSize=10
locationdb.c3p0.maxIdleTime=200

optout.endpoint=https://localhost:8443/
```

My buddies have their project setup successfully, but mine is having this error. Is there anything that I should consider in configuration?

Comment: Looks like incompatible jars: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.<init>(IZLjava/util/Timer;Ljava/lang/String;)V`

Comment: Looks like you have a non working version of C3P0. I would suggest a different datasource like HikariCP instead of C3P0.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have the latest version of C3P0 and all of my buddies' work station are working. Is there any configuration that I should set in my device or anything?

Comment: I still wouldn't use C3P0 (but that is IMHO) make sure you are using the same java version and all other libraries are the same. Looks like a compatibility issue judging from the error. You ar using Java7 try 6 or 8.

Comment: @Jens Do you know a work around for this?

Comment: @Aaron which version of c3po do you use?

Comment: @Jens it is 0.9.1.2.

Comment: @Jens apparently, everyone on my team uses the same configuration. I don't if what's happening with mine.

Comment: Is there any port conflict with this one?

Comment: Set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto as create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like version incompatibility of libraries. A very good ( but verbose) way to find out is by using `"-verbose:class"` in the JVM parameter of the server startup. This would generate a lot of logs so I prefer to output it to a file on server startup command line. On carefully searching for the Class in question, the logs will also print the jar and it's location from where the classloader picked this class. This could give a hint as to what is the compatibility issue.

Comment: This worked, however I didn't use the verbose. I have two jars for c3p0, one from hibernate and the c3p0 mchange. I deleted the one from Hibernate