# Getting No such method error webservice wildfly 10 (working on local machine)

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly-10

I am writing a webservice suddenly i am getting following error.
I am running webservice on wildfly10 and jdk 8 , rhel server

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.<init>(IZLjava/util/Timer;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.<init>(IZLjava/util/Timer;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.createTaskRunner(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:145)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.poolsInit(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:174)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.<init>(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:295)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getPoolManager(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:520)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at com.eko.axisweb.axiswebservice.hibernate.HibernateDataAccess.buildSessionFactory(HibernateDataAccess.java:37)
    at com.eko.axisweb.axiswebservice.ApplicationInitializer.initializeHibernate(ApplicationInitializer.java:74)
    at com.eko.axisweb.axiswebservice.ApplicationInitializer.init(ApplicationInitializer.java:41)
    at com.eko.axisweb.axiswebservice.ApplicationInitializer.contextInitialized(ApplicationInitializer.java:35)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more

2016-11-07 20:54:20,391 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management task-7) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: (undefined) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./axiswebservice" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./axiswebservice: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.<init>(IZLjava/util/Timer;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.<init>(IZLjava/util/Timer;Ljava/lang/String;)V"}}
```

**Strange thing is that in my local machine it is working file**
I don't know where is the exact problem.
I would be great if somebody help.

Resolution:
I have figured out that in my project two jar conflicting, so i started digging out and found that there are two c3p0 dependencies was there, one that i have added and another in quartz dependency. So i have changed my pom.xml like this.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
                <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It looks like you have a missing dependency or a library incompatibility. Here is a related question that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140621/error-creating-bean-with-name-transactionmanager-beancreationexception

Comment: Slightly off topic but you might consider using the built-in WildFly JDBC connection pool rather than a 3rd party one. That will eliminate the above issue if nothing else.

Comment: It has been resolved. Actually i was using hibernet c3p0 dependency and quartz  for scheduling task. quartz itself has c3p0 in it's dependency so i have excluded c3p0 from quartz dependency and problem resolved.
thanks

Comment: @ROHIT: You answered this yourself, and that helped me :-). If you post your solution as an actual answer, I would up-vote it.

Comment: @Lars : I have added solution that worked for me.